# Display Youtube videos in a gallery of thumbnails with a primary player

Tags: 7, views, files, media

I'd like to be able to display a gallery of youtube video thumbnails underneath a primary Youtube video "player" area. When a thumbnail is clicked, that video would play in the main player area without the user being taken to any other page. Is there a way I can accomplish this with existing modules and/or Views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have make something like this using views slideshow.

- Added youtube thumbnail in the views
- Added youtube video in the views
- Add slideshow as style format of the view
- Set youtube thumbnail in pager of the slideshow

Its working for me.

Comment: Perfect! I used the Youtube module, as mentioned by develkar below, since it includes the Youtube thumbnail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I make something like that using javascript

1. I make a block view that display all youtube thumbnail I need
2. I will rewrite the results of the image and make a rel attribute
   that contains the youtube url
3. make a block view that display the first youtube video
4. using javascript change the src of the youtube object to the rel attribute in the image when I click on it

Comment: That sounds like it would work really well. Would it be possible for you to share an example of your Javascript code that does this for you? Thanks!

Comment: just I make onclick javascript function and replace the youtube object (All the object <object>) with a new object with the new src,The code I made is more complicated I was replaced video sometimes with image and sometimes with uploaded video ,your case is simple than that

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a module named [youtube](http://drupal.org/project/youtube) in your drupal website and other modules required to upload a video.
2. create a VIEW-BLOCK.
3. in the FIELDS tag,add the TITLE of the VIDEO, and also the content-name of the field which has video "VIDEO".
   4.in the FILTER CRITERIA ,add the content type which you want to be displayed.
4. place the BLOCK in the region where you want the list of vides.